# Access a dictionary's keys given a list of keys using dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary-comprehension

I'm new to Python and I am trying to understand dictionary comprehension better. Suppose I have a dictionary with a large set of keys, and list contain a smaller subset (but a bit large) of keys in the dictionary. How would you, if it is possible, using dict comprehension, access all the values with the keys in the list?

```
nw_dt = {}
for i in range(101):
    nw_dt[chr(i)] = randint(0, 101)
ky_lit = [chr(b) for b in range(50, 101)]
```

What I have tired are the following:

```
for kys in nw_dt:
    nw_dt[f'{kys for v in ky_lit}']
```

But the string is a generator expression which returns a KeyError

I've also tried to search for a single key:

```
for kys in nw_dt:
    nw_dt[f'{kys if kys == chr(51)}']
```

It returns a EOF parsing error for the string

Comment: But why would you use a *dictionary* comprehension, do you want a *list* of keys, or a dictionary from only a subset of keys? *list* comprehensions build *lists*, dictionary comprehensions build *dictionaries*. Can you provide inputs with expected outputs? Note, if you want a list of keys, you can just do `ky_list = list(nw_dt)` if you have some list of keys, and want the values in `some_dict`, do `[some_dict[k] for k in keys_list]`

Comment: Use dictionary comprehensions outside of format strings.

Comment: Your question is not very clear but this will probably do: `{key: value for key, value in nw_dt.items() if key in ky_lit}`

Comment: I'm trying to alter the value in nw_dt but only for a subset of keys without creating a new dictionary. However, my issue is that I'm trying to be pythonic and access all the keys all at once and I'm not able to. i.e search for a key in the ky_lit and if it exists change its value in nw_dit.

Comment: Loop over the list of keys, if it exists in the dictionary, then alter. That seems pythonic. If you want to alter a dictionary, then don't use a dictionary comprehension, that's not what they are for.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list in the dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: nw_dt[key] for key in ky_lit}
```

A dictionary comprehension *creates* a new dictionary, but it can iterate over any iterable type.